# How do I calculate $\lim \limits_{x \to 8} (\sqrt[3]x-2/(x-8))=1$ using $x^n-a^n = (x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+x^{n-3}a^2+...+xa^{n-2}+a^{n-1})$?

Tags: calculus

I am asked to calculate the $\lim \limits_{x \to 8} (\sqrt[3]x-2/(x-8))=1$ using the factorization formula

$x^n-a^n = (x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+x^{n-3}a^2+...+xa^{n-2}+a^{n-1})$

I have rewritten the limit as

$\lim \limits_{x \to 8} (x^{1/3}-8^{1/3}/(x-8))=1$

I know that $x-8$ will cancel out, however I do not know how to plug in the values of $x$ and $a$ into the formula. I do not know where to stop plugging in values, the fractional exponent is confusing me.

Comment: $x = (x^{1/3})^3, 8 = (8^{1/3})^3$. Use the formula where $n = 3$ to the denominator.

Comment: You mean $\lim_{x\to 8} ((x^{1/3}-8^{1/3})/(x-8))?$    [Note parentheses]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ $x-8 = \left (x^{\frac 1 3} \right )^3 - (2)^3 = \left (x^{\frac 1 3} - 2 \right) \left (x^{\frac 2 3} +2 x^{\frac 1 3} +4 \right).$

So for $x \neq 8$ we have $\frac {x^{\frac 1 3} - 2} {x-8} = \frac {1} {x^{\frac 2 3} +2 x^{\frac 1 3} +4}.$ So taking limit $x \rightarrow 8$ in both sides of the equation we get $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 8} \frac {x^{\frac 1 3} - 2} {x-8} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 8} \frac {1} {x^{\frac 2 3} +2 x^{\frac 1 3} +4} = \frac {1} {12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note:  $x-8=(x^{\frac13}-2)(x^{\frac 23}+2x^{\frac13}+4)$.

The limit,  then, is $\frac1{12}$.